# Imbalanced Dataset in weka? Does not work

Tags: classification, weka

I have a positive dataset of 239 and negative dataset of 32 in number since its a cancer related data we had only few negative set. Now when applying classification , sure the imbalanced dataset will be biased too much towards the positive because of their huge numbers. So i tried applying SMOTE in weka . I tried various percentage and nearest neighbours too. to my suprise instead of negative class increased a few instances and the positive increased further making the imbalanced dataset too biased. What can be done to overcome this . And suggest me some other methods too ?? if available

For initial studies we used LIBSVM with RBF as classifier

Answer (score 2):

In this imbalanced dataset problem, I suggest to make use of *stratification*, which involves over-sampling the minority class or down-sampling the majority class. You can simulate stratification in WEKA making use of *cost sensitive classification*.

You can make use of two classifiers, [MetaCost](http://weka.wikispaces.com/MetaCost) and [CostSensitiveClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/CostSensitiveClassifier.html). The only issue is that the optimal values in the cost matrix can only be obtained by experimenting. As a rule of thumb, you can try to balance the class distribution by using weights that are inverse to the class distribution. In your case, this means assigning a cost of 239 to false positives and a weight of 32 to false negatives in the cost matrix.

Comment: As u said i was able to assign 239 FP and but when i change FN to 32, and save the cost file shows that FN is 1.0 only. i tried changing it several times but i could not change to 32.0. My question is i could not edit the cost matrix. how to do it . Whatever value i give as FN its considering as 1.0

Comment: Wow! it works!!! I tried to save the cost file and "Load as on Demand Cost File" . It works like "Easy Juicy Lemon Squeezy". The same kind i have tried in Libsvm in terminal with weights but not used to GUI version. Now its works good as per your comments.. Thank U

Comment: Happy about that. Good luck with your tests!